# How can I add encryption to my own TCP-based-Protocol using Java Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, encryption, tcp

So, I have a working protocol that the Client needs to authenticate with user and password to login on the server. Then server and client would trade messages and files. It´s all working OK and I´m using Input/Output Stream for that.
I need to add encryption to the conversation and user/password authentication too. I dont want to store a symmetric key inside my jar, So I think I will need a public/private keys for that.
I know I could use the public/private encryption to send a symmetric key, but I really dont know how to do that in Java. And I think I could maybe just use encryption on the messages and not on file transfer.

I googled for it and found various ways of using cryptography with java sockets, whats the best(correct) way? Using CipherOutput(Input)Stream? Or is there another way?

If someone could post a piece of code I would be grateful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL. See javax.net.ssl and the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: thanks, it looks great and simple, but can I use it with NIO for the server too??

Comment: Yes but with great difficulty. See the SSLEngine. But it's not for the faint-hearted.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a bind for time, you can piggy back on [SSH port forwarding](http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html).

You will setup firewall rule on your server that would allow direct access to clear text port only from the firewall host.

Then on a client you will setup a port forwarding SSH session ( -L option on ssh client ).

The client machine then will talk clear text to a local host on the forwarded port and all conversation will be encrypted by SSH tunnel.

Comment: Its also a good idea, but I need to implement as a commercial software and not beeing able to count with any firewall rule.